# Layout on website white space right side tablets

Tags: css, layout, whitespace

Hi designed a website the layout is fine in normal browsers but as soon as i have a look on the blackberry playbook theres a huge white space on the right side. same on the apple devices. here is the css code if you want to see if u go onto http://u-zuki-designs.com/beta you can see. thankyou

```
`enter code here`/*
Theme Name:u-zuki-designs
Thema URL:www.u-zuki-designs.com
Author Name:u-zuki-designs.com
Version:1.0
*/

@charset "utf-8";

/*Juneral Tag Properties Initilization*/
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body{

}

a{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

a img{
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.leftside{
    float:left;
}

.rightside{
    float:right;
}

.main{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
/*Juneral Tag Properties Initilization*/

/*Header Starting*/
.header{
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/header_bg.png) top left repeat-x;
}

.header_in{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:86px;
}

.header_menu{
    padding:35px 0px;
}

.header_menu ul li{
    float:left;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding:0px 6px;
}

.header_menu ul li a{
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px 10px;
}

.header_menu ul li a.active{
    background:#252435;
}

.header_menu ul li a:hover{
    background:#252435;

}

/*Header Ending*/

/*Banner Starting*/
.banner{
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/banner_bg.png) top left repeat-x;
}

.banner_in{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:395px;
}

.banner_in h1{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}

.banner_in .slider{
    width:655px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
/*Banner Ending*/

/*Content Starting*/
.content{
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/content_bg.png) top left repeat-x;
    min-height:542px;
}

.content_in{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1000px;
}


.category{
    border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;    
}

.category_in{
    width:210px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.category_in ul li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 3px;
}

.new_work{
    padding-left:90px;
}

.new_work .section_title h2{
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:18px;
}

.new_work .section_title a{
    color:#6dc6b6;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:10px;
    padding:0px 150px 0px 100px;
}

.new_work .website{
    color:#959595;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:12px;
}

.new_work .identity{
    color:#959595;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:12px;
}

.new_work .photography{
    color:#959595;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:10px;
}

.new_work .website p,
.new_work .identity p,
.new_work .photography p{
    font-size:10px;
}

.new_work .website p span,
.new_work .identity p span,
.new_work .photography p span{
    color:#2eae96;
}

.new_work .website,
.new_work .identity,
.new_work .photography{
    width:150px;
    padding:0px 10px;
}

.time_sep{
    font-size:10px;
    color:#b6b6b6;
    margin-left:100px;
}

.feature_icon_set{
    padding-left:130px;
}

.section_title_2 h3{
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:10px;
}

.section_title_2{
    padding-right:110px;
}

a.iconset{
    color:#42b4a1;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:10px;
}

.icon_set_display{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:175px;
    width:544px;
}

/*Content Ending*/

/*Footer Starting*/
.footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
}

.footer_in{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:200px;
}

.top_footer{

}

.top_footer .aboutus{
    padding:25px;
    width:150px;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:12px;
    color:#9f9fa2;
}

.top_footer .facebookupdate{
    padding:25px;
}

.top_footer .recent_work{
    padding:25px;
}

.top_footer .recent_work img{
    padding:3px;
}

.top_footer .aboutus h4,
.top_footer .facebookupdate h4,
.top_footer .recent_work h4{
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#777777;
}

.bottom_footer{
    padding-left:25px;
}

.bottom_footer ul li{
    float:left;
    color:#ccccce;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    padding:5px 3px;
}

.bottom_footer ul li a{
    color:#6e6e6e;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size:10px;
}
/*Footer Ending*/

/*Font Initilization Starting*/

/*Font Initilization Ending*/

html code 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/pascal/pascal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/orman/orman.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>U-Zuki-Designs | The Secrect To Creativity</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Code Starting-->
<div class="main">
  <!--Header Starting-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_in">
      <div class="logo leftside">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo1.png" alt=" " /></a>
     <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt=" " /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="header_menu rightside">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Header Ending-->
  <!--Banner Starting-->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_in"> 
      <br />
      <h1>Welcome To Our Website</h1>
      <br />
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div class="ribbon"></div>
        <!--<img src="images/banner_image.png" alt=" " />-->

                <div id="wrapper">

                <div id="slider-wrapper">

                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <img src="images/C.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="images/b.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <img src="images/ab.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="images/D.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <!--<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                        <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
                    </div>-->

                </div>

            </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Banner Ending-->
  <!--Content Starting-->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content_in">
      <br />
      <div class="category">
        <div class="category_in">
          <!--<ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/all.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/art.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/web.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/print.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/illustration.png" alt="" /></a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <br />-->
        </div>
        </div>
      <br />
      <div class="new_work">
            <div class="section_title leftside">
              <h2>New Work</h2>
              <br />
              <br />
              <a href="#"><h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;> View all illustrations</h4></a>
            </div>
            <div class="website leftside">
              <span>Website</span><br />
              <img src="images/website.png" alt=" " />
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<span>typesetting industry.</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="identity leftside">
              <span>Idenitity</span><br />
              <img src="images/identity.png" alt=" " />
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<span>typesetting industry.</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="photography leftside">
              <span>Photography</span><br />
              <img src="images/photography.png" alt=" " />
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<span>typesetting industry.</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="time_sep">
          12.09.2011<img src="images/sep_date.png" alt=" " />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="feature_icon_set">
          <div class="section_title_2 leftside">
            <h3>FEATURE: ICON SET</h3>
            <br />  
            <br /> 
            <br />   
            <a href="#" class="iconset">> View full datalis</a>
          </div>
          <div class="icon_set_display leftside">
        <h2><p><b>Our Work</b></p></h2> 
        <br>Welcome to our online graphic design & Photography portfolio. we hope you will see the quality of the our creaitivity we produce and maybe get a understanding of our passion for what we do to add smiles to our clients faces</br>



          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <br />
          <img src="images/sep2.png" alt=" " />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Content Ending-->
  <!--Footer Starting-->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_in">
      <div class="top_footer">
        <div class="aboutus leftside">
          <h4>Our Work</h4>
          <p><br>Our work with our clients is to explore, architect, rebuild, revise, revisit, rebrand, rewrite, rearchitect, and we do it all from start to finish...</br></p>
        </div>
        <div class="facebookupdate leftside">
          <h4>facebook updates</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="recent_work leftside">
          <h4 style="padding-left:3px;">recent works</h4>
          <img src="images/recent1.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <img src="images/recent2.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <img src="images/recent3.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <img src="images/recent4.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <img src="images/recent5.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <img src="images/recent6.png" alt=" " class="leftside"/>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <img src="images/footersep.png" alt=" " style="padding-left:25px;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_footer">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li>/</li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li>/</li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li>/</li>
          <li><a href="#">TERMS</a></li>
          <li>/</li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Footer Ending-->
</div>
<!--Code Ending-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="nivo-slider/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({});
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where. I checked your site in FF and i got the problem in PC itself. I dont have the smart phone right now but i think your problem will solve by simply remove the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove width from below css

```
.footer_in{
    /*width:1000px;*/
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:200px;
}
```

Without removed the width Screen Shot:

[image]

Width removed from .footer_in Screen Shot: No horizontal scroll bar.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dinesh...i am facing same problem when i keyboard appears on ipad..on dismiss of keyboard page doesn't go to original position...please see if can help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be due to the width of the header graphics and information.  If you condense your browser window, you will receive (what I'm assuming is) the same white space as the header content stretches out to the right side farther.  In a mobile environment not capable of displaying the whole width, as well, would in turn be stretched and present that white space.

I know this isn't a fix but I think this is the reason behind the white space you are seeing.

Comment: thank you guys. what would be the easiest option. i taken the width off and still see the white spaces when i resize the browser